# Как в C++ обойти ограничение cin на ввод более 4094 символов?

Tags: c++, строки

я тут немного экспериментировал со строками string, и столкнулся с одной интересной проблемкой, в общем если создать строку, то мы можем спокойно присвоить ей и 10 000 символов и 20 000, и в консоль такая строка так-же выводиться спокойно, не теряя ни одного символа. Но почему-то если мы хотим ввести через cin или getline(cin, text) она может принять только 4094 символа, так вот есть ли возможность как-то это обойти?

Если кому не понятно вот код.

```
string a;
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
   a += 'a';

cout << a.length() << endl; // длина 5000 все нормально!
//код 2

string a;
getline(cin, a); //Например ввели 5000 символов
cout << a.length() << endl; // длина будет 4094
```

то есть все что было после 4094 просто потерялось.

Comment: Стоит привести в вопросе конкретный пример кода

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j978pwMZjmE

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107331/buffer-size-limit-for-getline-in-c

Comment: сколько выделяется память для буфера std::basic_istream<char, char_traits<char>>, столько и вы можете вводить, пока не очистите буфер и не введете заново.

Comment: Никто  не мог подозревать, что у кого то возникнет  желание ввести в ручную из консольного приложения  несколько тысяч символов, чтобы выделить для его буфера большую память